# WordPress Translation not working for my theme

Tags: multisite, translation

Hi I've been trying to translate a string on my website using the translation function __( and
_e and I'm not seeing it working on my site.

for example i have a string on my site

__( 'Show articles', 'my_theme' )

show articles remains as it is as i switch my website to different languages my site is using MLP.

Comment: Did you add a translated string in the `.pot` file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the translation functions are being loaded. Sometimes, issues with function loading can prevent translations from working.

Basic example of loading translations in your theme's `functions.php` file

```
function my_theme_load_textdomain() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'my_theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_load_textdomain' );
```

Comment: I have them loaded im actually using generate press theme for my site.
It was initially loaded like this 

`load_theme_textdomain( 'generatepress' );`

added it like this

`load_theme_textdomain( 'generatepress', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );`

and still my string is not getting tranlated